# protect the known_host file from writing - good or bad idea?

Tags: linux, ssh, security, shell-script, known-hosts

I want to protect the known_host file from writing
So I want to perform the following steps on my Linux red-hat server

```
Cp /dev/null   /root/.ssh/known_hosts
chattr +i /root/.ssh/known_hosts
```

I want to that that because I want to prevent the unsuccessfully login to any target machine and that because sometimes we get the warning - **Remote Host Identification Has Changed** error and  login is failed

But I am not sure if my solution (writing protect on known_host )  is a good idea and what’s the negative affect on the Linux system ?

Or maybe this solution is a good solution to keep the **known_host** file as empty?

What the members here think about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO It's not a good idea (see below).

The following command will remove the offending key of your host from the known_hosts

```
  ssh-keygen -R <host>
```

e.g.  `ssh-keygen -R my_old_client`

Why this is not a good idea can be argued from `man ssh` (searching down you can read):

> Additionally, **the server must be able to verify the client's host key** (see the description of  /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts and ~/.ssh/known_hosts, below) **for login to be permitted**.  ***This authentication method closes security holes due to IP spoofing, DNS spoofing, and routing spoofing.***  [Note to the administrator: /etc/hosts.equiv, ~/.rhosts, and the rlogin/rsh protocol in general, are inherently
>   insecure and should be disabled if security is desired.]

---

Some words more: if `ssh` prompt you that the *machine key* it is changed usually it is because you reinstalled *ssh* on that machine, or maybe you forced a rebuild of the keys. However it's not anymore the *ssh key* that was used last time... it can be another computer that try to take that identity. If you are sure it's the same computer you can remove / update the offending key and go ahead.

Always from `man ssh` about how does it works:

> **ssh automatically maintains and checks a database containing identification for all hosts** it has ever been used with.
>   Host keys are stored in ~/.ssh/known_hosts in the user's home directory.  Additionally, the file `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` is automatically checked for known hosts.  Any new hosts are automatically added to the user's file.  **If a host's identification ever changes, ssh warns about this and disables password authentication to
>   prevent server spoofing or man-in-the-middle attacks**, which could otherwise be used to circumvent the encryption.
>
> The **StrictHostKeyChecking** option can be used to control logins to machines whose host key is not known or has   changed.

Comment: from man ss i not see they wrote known_host

Comment: is it better to do StrictHostKeyChecking no in ssh config?

Comment: People usually do not reinstall `ssh` purging the key so often. If you correct one time the problem when it happens you will not face this problem again (at least for a long while) and you will not compromise the security. Updated answer

Comment: StrictHostKeyChecking no and UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null will do the job , what you think? with this conf the file will stay empty